# Realm unmanaged object 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.' Swift3

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm, objectmapper

I know there are a lot discussion about 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.', but my case a bit different, at least to my eyes...

So I have the following data structure

```
class User: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var photo: Photo?
}

class Photo: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var cover: CoverPhoto?
    let photos = List<PhotoData>() // User uploaded photos, not cover
}

class CoverPhoto: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic var user: String?
    var photos = List<PhotoData>() // Different size of cover photo
}

class PhotoData : Object, Mappable {
    let width = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let height = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var url : String?
}
```

I am using ObjectMapper with alamofire to map my realm objects received via rest response.

The use data is already managed and in realm db.
There is a functionality to change cover photo thus via rest receiving the new set of cover photo list and wanted to replace it.
For that reason I'm replacing it by first remove existing and appending new one.
The problem occurred when trying to access to new data which received via rest which supposed to not be a managed object, but getting exception mentioned in description.

The code which updating realm object is below and it called right after received response via alamofire, so no any DB actions in between

```
    func updateCoverPhotos(userData: User, photo: Photo, onSuccess: ((Bool) -> Void)?, onError: ((NSError) -> Void)?) {
        let userDataRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: userData)
        let photos = photo.photos
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            do {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                realm.refresh()
                guard let user = realm.resolve(userDataRef) else {
                    return // user was deleted
                }

                try realm.write {
                    user.photo!.cover!.photos.removeAll()
                    user.photo!.cover!.photos.append(objectsIn: photos)
               }

               DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                 print(photoData) // Exception thrown 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'
                 onSuccess?(true)
              }

             } catch let error as NSError {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    onError?(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you please have a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong here ?

**UPDATED**

Mapping right after response, which contains new list of: PhotoData

```
        return alamofireManager.request(url, method: .post,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: alamofireManager.buildHeaders())
            .validate()
            .responseObject(keyPath: "data") { (response: DataResponse<Photo>) in
```

Comment: Wait, where is the line that throws the exception? Inside `DispatchQueue.main.sync`? Is `photoData` managed object?

Comment: That's the problem, that should not be managed, but in fact it is, it is just mapped from alamofire response

Comment: Does ObjectMapper Mapper() also creates managed object ?
And how I can check if it is managed or not ?

Comment: if `obj.realm` is set, then it is managed in swift afaik

Comment: Your code snippet shows you accessing a `photos` property on a `PhotoData` object, but your model definition does not include such a property. Can you please update your code to include it?

Comment: @bdash: thanks for noticing it, I tried to keep as small as possible forgot to change.

Comment: @mihatel The error message said `photoData` is managed. Can you make sure `photoData.realm` is `nil` before `print(photoData)`?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi: sorry for late reply...
Yes this property is nil

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi: I added few more prints, and it becomes managed (photoData.realm not nil) after appending photos (this line: user.photo!.cover!.photos.append(objectsIn: photos)). To be honest can't understand how :(